# envoy How to forward all ports

Tags: envoyproxy

I have this config for loadbalancerm even this is just one

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: apiserver_6443
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 6443
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: apiserver_proxy
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
                cluster: apiserver
                stat_prefix: svc_tcp_proxy
  clusters:
    - name: apiserver
      connect_timeout: 3600s
      lb_policy: round_robin
      type: STATIC # strict_dns
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: "apiserver"
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
         - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: 192.168.64.1
                  port_value: 60051
          - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: 192.168.64.2
                  port_value: 60052
```

Is it possible to forward all ports?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, can you give an example? What do you mean by "all ports"? Are you referring to 60051 and 60052?

Comment: Thanks, I am debugging calico on a cluster and wanted to see if it is the loadbalancer not opening some ports. First thought was to open all ports, but just opening any extra ports looks like a lot of writing?